# why old fingerprint can't be recognized after a period of time in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, fingerprint

recently, I was looking into fingerprint feature in Android 6.0(api 23), cause I have no real device with fingerprint sensor, so I just test this feature in emulator, but after a period of time like 10 hours, old fingerprint can't be recognized, I must add a new fingerprint in Settings then it could be recognized and authenticate successfully, was it a bug in emulator or my code has some bug?
below is some of my code:

```
    public void startListening() {
    if (!isFingerprintAuthAvailable()) {
        return;
    }
    mCancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
    mSelfCancelled = false;
    mFingerprintManager.authenticate(null, 0, mCancellationSignal, this, null);
    mIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fp_40px);
}
```

Comment: how did you add a fingerprint in emulator?

Comment: @Sharmilee use adb command:adb -e emu finger touch 1